# How do I convert a Week Number to From date of the week in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I enter WeekNo: 14 the query should return the From Date: April 4th 2016, since the week 14 starts from 4th April to 10th April

```
select to_date('14','iw') FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

something like this ? (it work for current year) there discard data from another years

```
with dates as (select to_char(
                        to_date('1.01.'||extract(year from sysdate),'dd.mm.yyyy'  ) + level -1 
                        ,'IW') we,
                        to_date('1.01.'||extract(year from sysdate),'dd.mm.yyyy'  ) + level -1 da
                 from dual 
                connect by level <= 365 + 10 )
select * from (
select case 
         when  -- we = null if number of week in jan > 1,2,3,4....
               ((to_number(we) > 40 )
               and extract(year from sysdate) = extract(year from da)
               and extract(month from da) = '01') or
               -- we = null when current year < year of da
               (extract(year from sysdate) != extract(year from da))
                then
                  null 
            else we
      end we,
      da
  from dates
)  
where we = 14
  and rownum = 1
```

Comment: This implies, that first week (according ISO standard) starts always 1st of January, however this is not the case.

Comment: i edit sql, and now this sql return correctly for current year of sysdate

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with ISO-Weeks is not trivial, for example January, 1st 2016 is week 53 of **2015**, see

```
select to_char(date '2016-01-01', 'iyyy-"W"iw') from dual;
```

So, providing only the week number without the (ISO-) year is ambiguous - although it is obvious as along as you are not around new-years date.

Some time ago I wrote this function to get the date from ISO-Week.

```
FUNCTION ISOWeekDate(week INTEGER, YEAR INTEGER) RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC IS
    res DATE;
BEGIN
    IF week > 53 OR week < 1 THEN
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;      
    END IF;
    res := NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE( YEAR || '0104', 'YYYYMMDD' ) - 7, 'MONDAY') + ( week - 1 ) * 7;
    IF TO_CHAR(res, 'fmIYYY') = YEAR THEN
        RETURN res;
    ELSE
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
    END IF;
END ISOWeekDate;
```

Of course you can just select `NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE( YEAR || '0104', 'YYYYMMDD' ) - 7, 'MONDAY') + ( week - 1 ) * 7;`, however this would not be error-safe if somebody uses the wrong year.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not an issue to append the year to the week you are looking for, you can also use this :

```
SELECT (TRUNC ( TO_DATE (SUBSTR ('201627', 1, 4) || '0131', 'YYYY'|| 'MMDD'), 'IYYY') 
    + ( 7 * ( TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR ('201627', 5)) - 1)) ) AS iw_Monday
FROM dual
```

With in this example `201627` being the `YYYYIW` you are looking for.
It will return the date of the MONDAY of that week.

Found it on [Oracle forums](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1015919?tstart=0), there are a couple of other solutions there. I found this one to be the most elegant.

The advantage is that you do everything from the `SELECT`, and you don't need either a function or PL/SQL or a `WHERE` clause.

Disadvantages : you must append the year and specify your search week 2 times, unless you use a variable

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and direct computation, taking advantage of various Oracle date functions. Since it compares to what Oracle already counts as ISO week etc., it shouldn't be subject to any of the difficulties other solutions correctly point to and address with additional code.

The "magic number" `14` in the formula should instead be a bind variable, perhaps `:iw`, or some other mechanism of inputting the ISO week number into the query.

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'iw') - 7 * (to_number(to_char(trunc(sysdate), 'iw')) - 14) as dt 
from   dual;

DT
----------
2016-04-04

1 row selected.
```

Comment: This does not work for dates in future, just for past weeks. Also the result is wrong when you execute the query for example on 1st January 2016.

Comment: I disagree on the first observation. This should work equally well in the future as in the past. I assume you didn't give it much thought; if you think you did, please explain why this shouldn't work for weeks in the future. On the second point, I agree in the sense that the OP needs to explain precisely which calendar year he/she needs the query for if it's run on 01-Jan-2016.